# Folder name in sidebar is changed, how to get it back?

Tags: macos, finder

My OSX is Simplified Chinese, so the user folders in finder's sidebar is like this:

```
AirDrop
应用程序
桌面
文稿
下载
影片
音乐
图片
```

These stand for AirDrop, Applications, Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Movies, Musics and Pictures.

However, now with an accident, my "Downloads" folders in sidebar is changed to its original english name, and I don't why, so my sidebar is now look like:

```
AirDrop
应用程序
桌面
文稿
Downloads
影片
音乐
图片
```

I know do symbol link to these folders would cause such case but I cannot find any symbol links to my `~/Downloads` folder.

So is there any way to get the Chinese name back? it looks so weired and dirty.

I have a time machine backup 3 days ago, but I have quite a lot modifications to my user folder these 3 days, so time machine may not be a good choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ~/Downloads/.localized does not exist, try creating it:

```
touch ~/Downloads/.localized
```

When the OS language is not English, there is normally an empty file named .localized inside each directory like ~/Downloads/ that has a localized name, and you can disable using localized names by deleting .localized files.

Comment: Works perfectly